# three.js rotation of camera around Y Axis seems off

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, rotation

We are doing a VR / Stereoscopic web application with three.js where we would like to display the angle at which the camera is looking.

Example:
We have a "room" setup. Camera in the center, at which point rotation of the camera is tied to the orbital controls.

```
# create a camera and place it in the scene
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, 1, 0.1, 2000);
camera.position.set(0, 35, 60);
# Attach Orbital controls
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, element);
controls.target.set(camera.position.x + 0.1, camera.position.y, camera.position.z);
controls.enableZoom = true;
controls.enablePan = true;
# Attach DeviceOrientationControls
controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(camera, true);
controls.connect();
controls.update();
```

Now during each animationFrame call, we check the camera's vector:

```
vector = camera.getWorldDirection();
theta = Math.atan2(vector.x, vector.z);
phi = Math.sqrt((vector.x * vector.x) + (vector.z * vector.z));
pitch = Math.atan2(phi, vector.y);
```

Expecting the following in radians:

- The theta to be the rotation away from the original view direction (Z), as if you would look down from the (Y) axis. (think of a clock on the ground below the camera)
- Phi would be the elevation from the original view direction (z) up or down.
  (Think of a clock on the side of the camera.)
- Pitch would be the rotation around the Z axis, when looking down the original Z vector. (think of a clock on the back of the camera.)

However, Theta seems be consistently off by a factor. Phi and Pitch seem ok.
We Transform the radians into degrees by doing for example: `pitch * (180/Math.PI)`

The world and camera itself seem to update and rotate just fine and rotating the phone / VR glasses to the left or right seem to produce and natural "looking around the room" movement.

Taking these measurements are done by checking the rotation over one axis at a time, and mostly keeping the other two facing the original direction.

What are we missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we managed to dig deeper into this. We build a cnc rotating table, and measured angles on the phones, and compared with the input we gave to the computer controlled rotating table.

Conclusion: Chrome is piece of crap. It cannot and will not produce even nearly useful data. Nor will it produce anything even remotely near repeatable.

Firefox on the same phones has some issues with flipping the axis at some points (probably gimbal lock related or something due to rotation overflowing over 360deg) but manages to be very much near our input (less than 1% off) and is super reliable and repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `camera.getWorldRotation()` to get [euler](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/4779db2dd2200e00905b9d248e938b9b54a82e53/src/math/Euler.js) angles.